# How to set MariaDB for particular databases pattern to replicate from mysql servers

Tags: mysql, database, debian, mariadb, master-slave

I have `mariadb` as slave and `mysql` servers as master.
I have to replicate the databases from `mysql to mariadb` and the databases are of one pattern `wws_*`.
If I add some databases on master with name starting with `wws_` it should replicate on mariadb `(my slave server)`
I tried by enabling `Binlog_do_db = wws_*` in my.cnf on master and `Replicate_do_db = wws_*` on slave but no luck.

How to make it functioning.

Comment: Partial/filtered replication is tricky business.  Is the master configured with `binlog_format` = `ROW`?

Comment: I tried to configure the master with `binlog_format` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard filtering of replication is available only for tables, not for databases.
If you have so many databases that this would be a useful feature, I would argue that your schema is not well structured.